# How to store only a part of the redux state using redux-persist

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

How can I store only a part of the redux-state using redux-persist. For example I have the following state

```
const initialState = {
data: [],
fetched: false,
loadingUser: false
}
```

How can I store only the data without saving fetched and loadingUser boolean with redux-persist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [whitelist and blacklist functionality, as outlined in the documentation.](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#blacklist--whitelist)

```
//in your redux store config 
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: ['data'] // only data will be persisted
};
```